# Mondrian drill through table in oracle shows integer values with comma

Tags: oracle, mondrian, drillthrough

**I have a problem using mondrian and JPivot**

The problem is that when I connect my application with an **Oracle** database, and access to the **drill through table**, all the values are shown with the format **2.010,00** that refers to the year **2010**.
This problem only happen with Oracle DB if I connect my application with a Postgres or SqlServer database the values are shown like 2010.

More information:

My cube has two dimensions: `CREATION_DATE` and `STATUS`, and one measure:

(*sorry, i have to change the tags for display in here, asume the next xml is in correct format*)

```
 -SCHEMA name="AAAA" envId="0"-
  -Cube name="AAAA" envId="0" cache="true" enabled="true"-
   -Table name="MY_FACT_TABLE" alias="MY_FACT_TABLE"-
   -Dimension name="FECHA_CREACION" envId="0"-
    -Hierarchy name="FECHA_CREACION" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All FECHA_CREACION"-
     -Level name="PRO_CREATE_YEAR" column="PRO_CREATE_YEAR" type="Integer" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never"-
     -Level name="PRO_CREATE_SEM" column="PRO_CREATE_SEM" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never"-
    -Hierarchy-
   -Dimension-
   -Dimension name="ESTADO" envId="0"-
    -Hierarchy name="ESTADO" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All ESTADO"-
     -Level name="PRO_STATUS" column="PRO_STATUS" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never"-
    -Hierarchy-
   -Dimension-
   -Measure name="MEASURE1" column="DW_PRO_ID" aggregator="count" visible="true" formatString="#,###.0" datatype="Numeric" caption="MEASURE1"-
  -Cube-
 -SCHEMA-
```

In the database, the table **MY_FACT_TABLE** has the column **PRO_CREATE_YEAR** with type '**INT**' and all the values inserted in that column where 2010 and 2011.

Drill Through Table for MEASURE1:

```
PRO_CREATE_YEAR | PRO_CREATE_SEM | PRO_STATUS | MEASURE1
2.010,00 | SEM1 | A | 1,00
2.010,00 | SEM1 | A | 3,00
2.010,00 | SEM1 | A | 2,00
```

I already tried to:
- change the levelType on the level PRO_CREATE_YEAR to "TimeYears".
- change the type of the dimension to "TimeDimension".
- change the type of the column PRO_CREATE_YEAR to number, number(9).
and nothing change.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by defining your dimension as a ["time" type](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#Time_dimensions). There are plenty of [examples out there](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/07/a-simple-date-dimension-for-mondrian-cubes/). This will allow you to use the full power of MDX's time functions and calculations.

You should also consider using the attributes nameColumn and captionColumn of the [level element](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/xml_schema.php#Level). You can get more details on these in Mondrian's [schema documentation](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php).

If you are willing to go the extra mile and contribute your findings with the members of the Mondrian community, feel free to reach out to the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/mondrian-devel) or file a bug report in the [tracking system](http://jira.pentaho.com).

Comment: Luc, thanks a lot for the answer. I already tried defining my dimension as a "time" type and nothing changes. I'm going to try to include the class MondrianDrillThrough.java and MondrianDrillThroughTableModel.java in my project and edit the method executeQuery() to control the format. If i sucess i'll published de solution. Thks a lot!

Comment: Besides the error is only with the Oracle DB, in others DB is just fine. None using JPivot/Mondrian with Oracle has this problem??

Comment: I recall that I've seen this before, and I dont think I fixed it at the time. but unfortunately I no longer have an oracle env to test against.